# WPF / WebBrowser - No overload matches delegate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to highlight some text in webbrowser (WPF). Unfortunately I can't get rid of the following error :

**No overload for 'Browser_LoadCompleted' matches delegate 'LoadCompletedEventHandler'**

This line is red underlined -> **StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML);**

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
using mshtml;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace LSS_doc.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ViewTabView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ViewTabView : UserControl
    {

        public ViewTabView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
            browser.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted;
        }


        public void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventHandler e)
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = browser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML);

            var words = new[] { "word", "word2" };
            foreach (String key in words)
            {
                String substitution = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>" + key + "</span>";
                html.Replace(key, substitution);
            }

            doc2.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like two problems. If you hover over the red underlined line you see the other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler is defined wrong.

Looking at [MSDN LoadCompletedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.loadcompletedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) which is what the [WebBrowser Control's LoadCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.loadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event uses, you need to use `NavigationEventArgs`.

```
public void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Regarding your redline about `StringBuilder`, I implore you to actually look at the error, look at the [constructor options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx), and verify what you are passing in.

Comment: I'm blind... Thank you so much. You are Star! I will accept the answer in 3 min as I'm not allowed yet.